# the sum function in XSLT(sum the attribute in the element)

Tags: xslt

sum the value the attribute in the element.How can do with the function `SUM()`?

My version of `xslt` is `version1.0.`

For example:

```
<catalog>
   <cds>
     <cd id='1' price='10'/>
     <cd id='2' price='20'/>
     <cd id='3' price='30'/>
     <cd id='3' price='-'/>
   </cds>
</catalog>
```

the result is 10+20+30=60,but skip the attribute with `'-'`

Comment: error result,correct answer is 60--sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can use a predicate `sum(/catalog/cds/cd/@price[number() = number()])` as the condition `number() = number()` will only be true for values convertible to numbers: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGd8

Comment: Thank you ! I have tried the predicate  sum(/catalog/cds/cd[@price != '-']/@price).It works.